# Python: Predefined class variable access

Tags: python

In Python, I am able to access the non-predefined class variables both from the class as well as instances. However, I am not able to access the predefined class variables (such as "**name**") from the object instances. What am I missing? Thanks.

Here is a test program that I wrote.

```
class Test:
        '''
        This is a test class to understand why we can't access predefined class variables
        like __name__, __module__ etc from an instance of the class while still able
        to access the non-predefined class variables from instances
        '''

        PI_VALUE = 3.14 #This is a non-predefined class variable

        # the constructor of the class
        def __init__(self, arg1):
                self.value = arg1

        def print_value(self):
                print self.value

an_object = Test("Hello")

an_object.print_value()
print Test.PI_VALUE             # print the class variable PI_VALUE from an instance of the class
print an_object.PI_VALUE        # print the class variable PI_VALUE from the class
print Test.__name__             # print pre-defined class variable __name__ from the class
print an_object.__name__        #print the pre-defined class varible __name__ from an instance of the class
```

Comment: Unlike a class, an instance doesn't have a defined name, so it doesn't have a `__name__`. Similarly, an instance is not defined in a module, so it doesn't have a `__module__`. Also, it's not true that instances cannot access pre-defined class variables: there's `__doc__` and `__weakref__`, for instance, as well as methods such as `__init__()`.

Comment: Thank you @ekhumoro. Your explanation makes definite sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal. Instances of a class look in that class's `__dict__` for attribute resolution, as well as the `__dict__`s of all ancestors, but not all attributes of a class come from its `__dict__`.

In particular, `Test`'s `__name__` is held in a field in the C struct representing the class, rather than in the class's `__dict__`, and the attribute is found through a `__name__` [descriptor](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20descriptors) in `type.__dict__`. Instances of `Test` don't look at this for attribute lookup.

Comment: Ah. That explains. Thanks @user2357112

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a great answer for "why". But here's how you can get to them, using __class__:

```
>>> class Foo(object): pass
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute '__name__'
>>> foo.__class__.__name__
'Foo'
>>>
```

Comment: Please see the above responses from @ekhumoro and user2357112.  Their responses also explain why foo.__class__.__name__ works.